# entitlement mediator with multiple tenants

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using APIM 3.1.0 with IS-KM 5.10.0 in a multi tenant deployment.I have an app created in carbon.super tenant and set of APIs created for this App. This app is a saas application available to all the tenants in the system. I need to enforce the XACML policies to each indiviual tenants. But to enforce the policies to each individual tenants I need create the different entitlement mediator xml files like below

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="EntitlementMediator">     
   <entitlementService xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" remoteServiceUrl="https://10.57.8.14:9443/services" remoteServiceUserName="abc@abc.com" remoteServicePassword="12345" callbackClass="org.wso2.sample.handlers.entitlement.APIEntitlementCallbackHandler"/>
</sequence>
```

But this configuration is per tenant and I cannot upload more than one mediator into message mediation path.

Please let me know how to achieve PEP to multiple tenants with APIs shared to multiple tenants via the SaaS application

Comment: Basically if you add an application to the super tenant, you cannot enforce any XACML policies to that application from another tenant. But if you can write a post-authentication-handler to handle the authorization, you can fulfil this requirement because from there we can get the authenticated users tenant domain. Then we can evaluate the XACML policy regarding that. Following link will describe how to create a post authentication handler : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-a-post-authentication-handler/#writing-a-post-authentication-handler.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am using OIDC SSO for the authentication mechanism. And authentication endpoint is API gateway and not ID server. Will it be still possible to perform this XACML validation which is a component provided by the WSO2 ID server?